# get elements in two components

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a React app. This app gets random elements from the server. After that user checks one and app get new elements. This app is very simple

```
getElements(){
  const id = this.props.id;
  axios.get(`ajax/elements/` + id)
    .then(res => {
      const elements = res.data;
      this.setState({ elements, loading: false });
     }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
     })    
}

render() {
  return <div className="container">
            <Elementlists elements={this.state.elements} />
         </div>             
}
```

I'm using the `getElements` method in order to get elements from the server (I'm using componentDidMount). The problem is I want to get new elements after user check elements (this is in other components) and I don't want to repeat the `getElements` method. At this time it looks like this.

```
onSelect(id){
  const select = {
    element_id: id
  }

  axios.post(`ajax/select`, { select })
    .then(res => {
      //someting
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        { this.props.elements.map(element => <li key={element.id}>
          <div onClick={() => this.onSelect(element.id)} className="singleElement"  style={ { backgroundImage: "url("+element.cover+")" } 
            }>
          </div>
         </li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

How I can get elements after the user checks one element without repeat code in other components?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use redux (or similar) for global app state management. Once you fetch the elements and store the redux app state, Then you can connect and use the elements in the app.